# Python - Trying to identify the lowest unused number in list of folders

Tags: python, loops

My office has folders listed 01200001, 01200002, etc. I am trying to return the lowest unused value from our list.

Here's my script so far:

```
import os

def Exst(yr, i):
    exst = [n for n in os.listdir("P:/20" + str(yr)) if '01' + str(yr) + str(i) in n][0]
    print(exst)

for i in range(0001, 9999):
    try:
        Exst(20, i.zfill(4))
    except:
        print("01" + str(yr) + str(i).zfill(4))
        break
```

I am getting the initial 01200001 value, but the loop doesnt seem to be incrementing until failure. In my except statement, I am trying to read the value that the try loop stopped working on.

I'm very new to Python, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: It probably means that your `break` statement is executed, hence breaking out of the loop at the first iteration. Consider removing it if that's not what you want?

Comment: This is a very common theme among beginners: printing is no substitute for returning a value.

Comment: be careful using a number literal like `0001`... any literal with a leading zero is treated as 'octal' (i.e. base 8) so for example `0010 == 8`.  In this case `0001 == 1` so you're ok anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search through existing folders, and return the first one that doesn't exist. So say you have

```
folders = os.listdir(...)
```

You can do a very simple implementation like this:

```
for i in range(1, 10000):
    if f'01{yr}{i:04d}' not in folders:
        return i
```

This will format the folder name for each index `i` and return the first index that's not in `folders`. When you format the index, be sure to use the format spec `04d`, so you always get a four character string, with zero instead of space padding.

But that method is inefficient: it performs a linear search for each index. A better way might be to sort the directory contents, find the index of the first match, and step along until you find a gap:

```
def find_min_index(yr):
    folders = os.listdir(...)
    folders.sort()
    try:
        start = folders.index(f'01{yr}0001')
    except ValueError:
        return 1
    expected = 2
    for expected, actual in enumerate(folders[start + 1:], start=2):
        if f'01{yr}{expected:04d}' != actual
            break
    return expected
```